# What is the iHDR process?

Tags: hdr

I've seen references to the iHDR process. I would like to read a quick summary, but I'm not quite interested enough to watch a webinar. What is the basic idea of iHDR?

Comment: Never heard of this. Sounds like an Apple product :) If it is, then they won't tell you what it does but ask more than its worth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, iHDR is a method of blending the bracketed raw images using a variety of masked luminosity layers.

As I understand it, it’s a series of steps for blending images, after refining and masking layers in each image, so as to produce results that represent what you saw in the original scene. This is all done manually, without using HDR software, in order that the photographer can just blend the areas of the images that he thinks needs it, rather than get the all over rather flat effect that some software can produce in some hands.

Comment: is it different from "normal" HDR?

Comment: Would you mind adding a little more detail?

Comment: Any links or book recommendations to further info would be great.